# Insert character after pattern with character exclusion using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have this string of file names.

```
FileNames="FileName1.txtStrange-File-Name2.txt.zipAnother-FileName.txt"
```

What I like to do is to separate the file names by semicolon so I can iterate over it. For the `.zip`extension I have a working command.

I tried the following:

```
FileNames="${FileNames//.zip/.zip;}"
echo "$FileNames" | sed 's|.txt[^.zip]|.txt;|g'
```

Which works partially. It add a semicolon to the `.zip` as expected, but where sed matches the `.txt` I got the output:

```
FileName1.txt;trange-File-Name2.txt.zip;Another-FileName.txt
```

I think because of the character exclusion `sed` replaces the following character after the match.

I would like to have an output like this:

```
FileName1.txt;Strange-File-Name2.txt.zip;Another-FileName.txt
```

I'm not sticked to `sed`, but it would be fine to using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a better way, but you can do it with `sed` like this:

```
$ echo "FileName1.txtStrange-File-Name2.txt.zipAnother-FileName.txt" | sed  's/\(zip\|txt\)\([^.]\)/\1;\2/g'
FileName1.txt;Strange-File-Name2.txt.zip;Another-FileName.txt
```

Beware that `[^.zip]` matches 'one char that is not `.`, nor `z`, nor `i` nor `p`'. It does not match 'a word that is not `.zip`'

Note the less verbose solution by @sundeep:

```
sed -E 's/(zip|txt)([^.])/\1;\2/g'
```

Comment: good one, `[^.]` also solves not adding `;` at end of line... you could also add ERE version `sed -E 's/(zip|txt)([^.])/\1;\2/g'`

Comment: Many thx for the replies. @Sundeep solution worked for me. The solution of @damienfrancois worked partially, when I remove the `zip\|`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -r 's/(\.[a-z]{3})(.)/\1;\2/g'
```

would be a more generic expression.